# Javascript code getElementByID for loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, getelementbyid

I can't figure out why the for loop below doesn't work.

I've created a function that does work so the HTML is not an issue.  Here is the function that works:

```
function deactivateAllTabs() {
    document.getElementById('tab-header-1').className = 'tab-header';
    document.getElementById('tab-header-2').className = 'tab-header';
    document.getElementById('tab-header-3').className = 'tab-header';
    document.getElementById('tab-content-1').className = 'tab-content';
    document.getElementById('tab-content-2').className = 'tab-content';
    document.getElementById('tab-content-3').className = 'tab-content'; 
}
```

Instead of hard-coding the tab-headers and tab-contents ids, I thought I'd create a for loop to automatically take care of future additional tabs.

If I respectively add another set of:

```
document.getElementById('tab-header-4').className = 'tab-header';
document.getElementById('tab-content-4').className = 'tab-content';
```

Everything works above.  It fails when I try the for loop below. Any idea where I am going wrong?

The error I get when clicking into a tab is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null

```
function deactivateAllTabs() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabHeaders.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('tab-header-'+i).className = 'tab-header';
        document.getElementById('tab-content-'+i).className = 'tab-content';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have elements with the ID `tab-header-0` and `tab-content-0`?

Comment: `document.getElementById('tab-header-'+ (i+1)).className = 'tab-header';` and same for the next line.

Comment: Thank you Matt - looks like you found it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop starts at 0, but your tab headers start at 1.

```
function deactivateAllTabs() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= tabHeaders.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('tab-header-'+i).className = 'tab-header';
        document.getElementById('tab-content-'+i).className = 'tab-content';
    }
}
```

Comment: True, but you've just posted the same broken code. Would be better to post the *fixed* code.

Comment: Now it won't get the last one

Comment: Thank you folks - how obvious.  (And I overlooked the loop starting at zero).  Always helps when another set of eyes have a gander.

Thanks again.  :)

Comment: And just to followup - correct.  The code works starting the loop at 1.  Thanks all for your input.  Please let me know if I'm missing something to credit you with the answer because I don't use this often...

Answer (score 0):

See Neil's answer for solution to your problem

This is an alternative answer using jquery

You can select all the tabs that start with the same name and change their class without looping.

```
$('div[id^="tab-header-"]').attr('class', 'tab-header');
$('div[id^="tab-content-"]').attr('class', 'tab-content');
```

Answer (score -1):

Your for loop is zero indexed but the tabs are one indexed. This should work by starting at 1 instead of 0. Right?

```
function deactivateAllTabs() {
    for (var i = 1; i < tabHeaders.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('tab-header-'+i).className = 'tab-header';
        document.getElementById('tab-content-'+i).className = 'tab-content';
    }
}
```

Comment: `i = i`? And if you meant, `i = 1`, you still need to fix `i <= tabHeader.length`

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use .

```
function deactivateAllTabs() { 
    for (var i = 0; i < tabHeaders.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('tab-header-'+i).setAttr(className, 'tab-header'); 
        document.getElementById('tab-content-'+i).setAttr(className,'tab-content'); 
    } 
}
```